# How to implement WebPage pattern and add Interface in save class test

Tags: c#, selenium

Please see this structure (from [here](https://automatetheplanet.com/advanced-page-object-pattern/)):

```
public abstract class AbstractPage<T> where T : AbstractPageEmenetsMap, new()
{
    protected readonly string url;
    protected VendorInfo vendorInfo;

    public AbstractPage(VendorInfo vendorInfo)
    {
        this.vendorInfo = vendorInfo;
        this.url = this.vendorInfo.Url;
    }

    public void Navigate()
    {
        WebDriver.Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(this.url);
    }

    protected T Map
    {
        get { return new T(); }
    }        
}

public abstract class AbstractPage<M, V> : AbstractPage<M>, ITest

    where M : AbstractPageEmenetsMap, new()
    where V : AbstractPageValidator<M>, new()
{
    public AbstractPage(VendorInfo vendorInfo)
        : base(vendorInfo) { }

    public V Validate()
    {
        return new V();
    }

    public void Login();
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Logout();
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And i want to add interface with some operations

```
public interface ITest
{
    void Login();
    void Logout();
}
```

Now this is `Son` class:

```
public class GmailPage : AbstractPage<GmailPageElementsMap, GmailPageValidator>, ITest
{
    public GmailPage() : base("http:...") { }
}
```

Class that holds all the elements:

```
public IWebElement EmailAddressTextBox
{
    get
    {
        return WebDriver.WebDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("identifierId")));
    }
}
```

And validator:

```
public class GmailPageValidator : AbstractPageValidator<GmailPageElementsMap>
{

}
```

As you can see i implement `ITest` from my `Gmail` class but i don't received any compile error although i do not add this 2 interface methods (Login and Logout).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because those methods are implemented in the parent `AbstractPage`. If you want to force `GmailPage` (and all other derived classes) to implement `Login()` and `Logout()` declare them as `abstract` in the parent `AbstractPage` class

```
public abstract class AbstractPage<M, V> : AbstractPage<M>, ITest
    where M : AbstractPageEmenetsMap, new()
    where V : AbstractPageValidator<M>, new()
{
    public AbstractPage(VendorInfo vendorInfo) : base(vendorInfo) { }

    public V Validate()
    {
        return new V();
    }

    public abstract void Login();

    public abstract void Logout();
}
```

And override in `GmailPage`

```
public class GmailPage : AbstractPage<GmailPageElementsMap, GmailPageValidator>
{
    public GmailPage() : base("http:...") { }
    public override void Login()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Logout()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```